# pygame на маке не находит файлы

Tags: python, pygame

Я пишу маленькую игру на pygame, и там будет счётчик баллов, который будет посконно перезаписываться в txt файл, для того, чтоб при перезапуске игры счёт оставался тем же. Когда я писал игру на ПК на Windows файл с текстом успешно запускался, но когда я перешёл на мак, появилась такая проблема.[image: finder, где находится игра]

[[image: сама ошибка][2]][image: код]

Answer (score 0):

Вполне вероятно что Python смотрит на другую папку, а не на ту где ваша папка с проектом. Попробуйте указать полный путь, либо работать с путями с помощью модуля os

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]